# Check Value On Array - PHP

Tags: php

How to check the condition in array, for example,

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['uploaded']['name']); $i++) {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $filesize = $_FILES['uploaded']['size'][$i];

    if ($tmpFilePath != '' || !empty($tmpFilePath)) {
        // if condition is true upload the images and stored in db.
    } else {
        //no image uploaded.
   }
}
```

In my case, user can upload up to 3 images. On the condition above, how to check:

```
Array
    (
        [1] => filename
        [2] => filename
        [3] => 
    )
```

The above will still be **true** but on my code, it will goes to false.

> **Solution**

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['uploaded']['name']); $i++) {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $filesize = $_FILES['uploaded']['size'][$i];

    if ($tmpFilePath != '' || !empty($tmpFilePath)) {
      // sql to insert to db here
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $pr_idEnc = urlencode(encryptor('encrypt', $pr_id));
        // mysqli_close($conn); 
        header("Location: ".BASE_PATH."update-purchase.php?success&pr_id=".$pr_idEnc."");                   
      } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        // mysqli_close($conn);
      }
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn); // edit here
```

Find out the problem is because of the `mysqli_close($conn)` inside the `for loop`. Please let me know or give me an advise if my coding is wrong or can be improve. Thanks

Comment: What goes to false? What isn't working?

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)` and see how it is posted. I guess you are using input array for file. Add the html also.

Comment: What will be true? Can you explaing what is the problem a little bit more?

Comment: If user upload for example only 2 files, it will not save the filename on db. User have to upload 3 images. If it get 1 empty file like the example above, it will not store the filename on db

Comment: found out the error was because I made the `mysqli_close($conn);` inside the for loop. That is why I am unable to save the file name on db.